# pyspark: How to obtain the Spark SQLContext of the spark dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a function that accepts a spark DataFrame and I would like to obtain the Spark context in which the DataFrames exists.

The reason is that I want to get the `SQLContext` so I can run some SQL queries

```
sql_Context = SQLContext(output_df.sparkContext())
sql_Context.registerDataFrameAsTable(output_df, "table1")
sql_Context.sql("select * from table1") # or some more complicated query
```

but of course `output_df.sparkContext()` doesn't work. What's right way to obtain the sparkContext of a Spark DataFrame?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`output_df.sql_ctx` is the answer

Answer (score 1):

`output_df.rdd.context` does the job

Comment: I've edited the answer. The property is actually called `context` not `sparkContext`. Sorry about that